# Jquery manipulate elements by a passed object reference

Tags: jquery, reference

I have this jquery code with me

```
$('.parent').livequery('change', function() {

        $(this).parent('.show_sub_categories').append('<img src="nlevel_ajax_dropdown/loader.gif" style="float:left; margin-top:7px;" id="loader" alt="" />');

        $.post("nlevel_chid_categories.php", {
            parent_id: $(this).val(),
        }, function(response){
            var ref = $(this).parent('.show_sub_categories');   
            setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories', '"+escape(response)+"','"+ref+"')", 400);
        });

        return false;
    });

});

function finishAjax(id, response,ref){
  $('#loader').remove();
  $(ref).append(unescape(response)); // and this is giving error 
}
```

What i want to make is call finishAjax function upon ajax completion and append the result to the parent of element on which event is fired, so i tried getting the referene of its parent by `var ref = $(this).parent('.show_sub_categories');` and passed it along with `finishAjax` call in `setTimeout` function but this is throwing jquery error.

Here is the actuall error message : 
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]` 
`(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e...y",[],function(){return v})})(window);`

Comment: Should add the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `.done()` instead of adding an extra parameter to `post`. Also, anonymous functions are more likely to be easier to debug, especially when you need to pass parameters in the `setTimeout` syntax. Try this :

```
$('.parent').livequery('change', function() {
    var ref=$(this).parent('.show_sub_categories');

    ref.append('<img src="nlevel_ajax_dropdown/loader.gif" style="float:left; margin-top:7px;" id="loader" alt="" />');

    var ajaxPost = $.post("nlevel_chid_categories.php", {
        parent_id: $(this).val()
    });

    ajaxPost.done(function(response){
        setTimeout(function(){
            finishAjax('show_sub_categories', response, ref);
        }, 400);
    });

    return false;
});
```

---

EDIT: Adjusted `ref` definition to use it all over + passing in an unescaped version of  `response` in the `.done` part.

Also, the `ref` that is passed in `finishAjax` is already a selector so it should be accessed directly at this point:

```
function finishAjax(id, response, ref){
    $('#loader').remove();
    ref.append(response);
}
```

Comment: @frederik-l nothing happend.. :'(

Comment: Actually the line is not getting the parent for $(this) var ref = $(this).parent('.show_sub_categories'); i have  checked this by putting it outside of the $.post call there is ahs parent.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it use the same selector. As for the other error, you need to make sure that you append a string and not an object. What does `nlevel_chid_categories.php` return ? Is it json or plain text ?

Comment: please see my last edit, it should do the trick according to what needs to be appened